# Merging three vectors with NaN's

Tags: r, vector, merge, na

I have three vectors that look something like this:

```
x = c(NaN, 15, 16, 14, 14, NaN)
y = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 11)
z = c(17, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 12)
```

I need to merge them into one vector. I need these three to mesh together smoothly, and where there are overlapping values (as seen in y and z), priority should be given to the value from z. The end result should look like so:

```
xyz = c(17, 15, 16, 14, 14, 12)
```

I've looked into using rowSums to handle the na's, but this doesn't work in cases where there are multiple values on the same index. I'm trying to avoid for loops if possible.

Pretty sure I could do this by iterating through the vectors but I'm working with a fairly large data set.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `NaN`?

Comment: Not a number -- Pretty sure these came from reading in empty cells from a .csv. They seem to work the same as NA's in that I can use na.rm in rowSums to manipulate them, but they print as NaN so I figured I should include it as such.

Comment: I am more used to `NA` than `NaN`, but I see it is a reserved word and a valid value. Interesting... (though not much help in your problem, I am afraid) :(

Comment: Did a bit of digging the last few days -- Turns out that integers can hold NA, but doubles can hold NA, NaN, Inf, or -Inf -- Allows for special cases in things like division. I encountered this because my tabulated data was read in as a vector of doubles. Anyways, not important to the solution, but I thought you might be interested in why both exist!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work. **NB** It relies on `z` being the last column of the data frame, then flips it so that it's first (i.e., `rev`).

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(NaN, 15, 16, 14, 14, NaN),
            y = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 11),
            z = c(17, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 12))

do.call(dplyr::coalesce, rev(df))
```

---

---

You can also use `zoo` package:

```
df <- rbind(x, y, z)

#it replaces last row with latest non-NA value therefore z always has priority:
xyz <- zoo::na.locf(df)['z',]

#[1] 17 15 16 14 14 12
```

***Data***:

```
x <- c(NaN, 15, 16, 14, 14, NaN)
y <- c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 11)
z <- c(17, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 12)
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll need to dig through the help files to get a grasp on WHY it's doing what I need, but this definitely does it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can using base R function `na.omit`

```
x = c(NaN, 15, 16, 14, 14, NaN)
y = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 11)
z = c(17, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 12)
dt=data.frame(z=z,x=x,y=y)
unlist(lapply(apply(dt,1,na.omit), `[[`, 1))

[1] 17 15 16 14 14 12
```